# Height and line-height styles not applied

Tags: css, height, line-height

Line-height and height not applied in these spans.
Here's the code: https://github.com/giniblanco/recipe-app
Thanks.
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwXWD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make to span `display: block;` style.
Seems like image tag brakes the line

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a class or id to the span tag and then try adding the styles to the class or id.